# Cannot close Ajax ModalPopupExtender Modal window which is created from a master page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a Website project with a master page with the standard default Microsoft theme that is created when starting a new project.
I created a Search page that I want to call from this menu and put the new anchor tag within this standard menu.  The click of the search link will pull up a modal and bring in my search.aspx page within it.

```
<li><a  href="#" onclick="Search(this)">Search</a></li>



function Search() {
     document.getElementById('<%= hdnButtonSearch.ClientID%>').click();
}
```

**This is the modal the source is a webform Search.aspx**

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalSearch" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panl1" TargetControlID="hdnButtonSearch"
     CancelControlID="Button2" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" ></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
     <asp:Panel ID="Panl1" runat="server" CssClass="Popup" align="center" style = "display:none">
     <iframe style=" width: 800px; height: 600px;" id="irm1" src="Search.aspx" runat="server"></iframe>
   <br/>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" />


</asp:Panel>
```

I could call this modal window from being on any of the webforms just by clicking the Seach link within the menu.

**Now the Problem.**
I Call and open up the modal extender and it opens the search.aspx webform.
On this webform I want to put a button to close the modal.
I don't want to use the standard button in this case Button2 within the ModalPopupExtender I want to use a button that is actually on the Search.aspx page.**

What will really happen is the user searches for a client the client goes inside a grid and then the client wants to view that client so they click a link button within the gird which loads the client and then I want the modal to close.

How could I close this modal within the search.aspx page?

The search page does not have a MasterPageFile its just a webform that pops up within the modal.

In the search page I have a button.  That calls the Javascript function to close the modal but it does not work I get an error.

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
>
> ```
>       function HideModalPopup() {
>             $find("ModalSearch").hide();
>             return false;
>         } </script>
> ```

Comment: I put this into my javascript function on the search page and it worked.

            function HideModalPopup() {
                parent.$find("ModalSearch").hide();
                return false;
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search.aspx page is being rendered into the modal but is effectively part of the same page. This isn't an iframe, so you can assume it has full access to the DOM and all the available scripts.

Whatever JavaScript function you already have in place to close the modal, call that from the relevant client-side control from your search.aspx page.

Comment: I did I have put it in a button click event    but it does not work from the search.aspx page.  I tried just about everything so not sure what to do.                                                   function HideModalPopup() {
                    $find("ModalSearch").hide();
                    return false;}

Comment: You were right I did have access to the parent.  I changed my javascript on the search.aspx page to refer to the client and it worked.


            function HideModalPopup() {
                parent.$find("ModalSearch").hide();
                return false;
            }

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted.